# Error occurred while connecting to camera in fragment after quick rotation

Tags: android, android-asynctask, camera, rotation, fragment

I have a custom camera using the android camera api (deprecated one), and I'm having an issue where if the device is rotated 90 degrees one way and quickly 90 degrees back the camera doesn't get released and won't reopen after rotation. If I rotate the device quickly one direction it works fine, just the quick rotation back and forth causes issues.

The camera is opened by an async task in a fragment, I have tried setting retain instance but then I get errors for the methods being called after release of the camera. I already release the camera onPause so I'm not sure what else I can do to make sure its release while it rotates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not retaining the instance and when the camera threw the RuntimeException I would catch it and call recreate on the activity and that was quick enough to get the camera after a quick rotation 90 degrees and back.